# Multiple loop in list comprehension

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I have a problem set in hand, the description is something like:

We have 2 lists ie "nums1" and "nums2" and 2 integers m and n

```
nums1 = [1, 2, 3, 7, 8, 9]
m = 3
nums2 = [2, 5, 6]
n = 2
```

Here "m" denotes number of elements to be picked from "nums1" and "n" denotes the number of elements to be picked from "nums2".
There are other ways ofcourse, but I want to create a list with only **"list comprehension"** on the above conditions.

With a simple `for` loop I can achieve that with:

```
li = []
for i in range(m):
  li.append(nums1[i])
for j in range(n):
  li.append(nums2[j])
print(li)
```

I tried the following but the outcome result is not as expected:

```
[a for a in nums1 for b in nums2]
```

**Expected output:**
[1, 2, 2, 3, 5]

Also, does list comprehension supports multiple loop?

Comment: sorting would be the last part, that can be ignored as well. I just want to know if list comprehension supports 2 or more loops.

Comment: Didi you consider slicing like `nums1[:m] + nums2[:n]` ?

Comment: `nums1[:m] + nums2[:n]`.

Comment: @VPfB that would slice only, and acceptable answer as well. But I want to merge the 2 list as per the conditions with "List comprehension" to be specific.

Comment: @ank You may think of the list comprehension as a nested for-loop rather than 2 seperate loops, do you see how that makes it more difficult and may explain your unintentional behaviour experienced? I think it's better to go with merging slices or two seperate loops.

Comment: You can use enumerate on list to get pairs of index and item and add condition to list comprehension that requires index to be smaller than n (m). Although it looks like a very convoluted solution to a simple problem, where slicing is much more appropriate. Or you can just re-write your loop with list comprehension. You will still have two comprehensions and not one. One comprehension with two lists is equivalent to a nested loo, that's why it didn't work for you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given the following:

```
nums1 = [1, 2, 3, 7, 8, 9]
m = 3
nums2 = [2, 5, 6]
n = 2
```

Using strictly list comprehension, the following does what you asked for:

```
sorted([nums1[a] for a in range(m)] + [nums2[b] for b in range(n)])
```

Returns:

```
[1, 2, 2, 3, 5]
```

> as per the conditions with "List comprehension" to be specific.

Although as others have said in the comment, a slice would have been more pythonic and easier to reason about. But since you asked for a list comprehension implementation, then this is as close to an answer as you'll get.

Comment: Understood. Thanks @onlyphantom

Comment: `sorted([x for x in nums1[:m] + nums2[:n]])` uses list comprehension as well

Comment: @luk2302 that's a good answer as well. Devang's solution works too. Many ways to approach this -- probably comes down to "cognitive overhead", whichever solution OP ends up with.

Answer (score 0):

```
nums1 = [1, 2, 3, 7, 8, 9]
m = 3
nums2 = [2, 5, 6]
n = 2

ll = sorted([a for b in [nums1[:m], nums2[:n]] for a in b])

print(ll)
```

Output

```
[1, 2, 2, 3, 5]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
nums1 = [1, 2, 3, 7, 8, 9]
m = 3
nums2 = [2, 5, 6]
n = 2
```

Create an empty list and store the returned values in this list if you need to access them later on in the program

```
nums3 = []
[nums3.append(nums1[i]) for i in range(m)]
[nums3.append(nums2[i]) for i in range(n)]
```

Sorts and prints the newly created list

```
print(sorted(nums3))
```